# How to store Pre-Shared keys securely?

Tags: c#, authentication, encryption

I Analyse possible implentation for storing Pre-Shared keys securely.

If data are encrypted by pre-shared keys, how to we store them in a securly on the client side?

Any idea?
I investigated but still don't have clue.

Comment: You can use [Windows Data Protection API (DPAPI)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms995355.aspx)

Comment: Sounds good. I will investigate. Do you have any experience with this?

Comment: This helps to encript/decript Pre-Shared keys. But where to store Pre-Shared key securly?

Comment: The question where is irrelevant considering the security, the more important question is how (the data is protected). Therefore DPAPI is a good answer considering that it is unknown what attacks may be possible if someone knows the PSK.